# Python, I am trying to make a leader board but it wont save in the text file can someone help me?

Tags: python

My code:

[leaderboard code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLAc2.png)

The file "leaderboard.txt" stays blank. They are both saved in the same folder.

code:

```
print ("1: Enter new high score.", "\n","2: Display scores.", "\n","3: Clear scores", "\n","4: Quit")
    choice = input("")
    while choice != "4":
        file = open("leaderboard.txt", "w")
        if choice == "1":
            score = input("what was your score")
            date = input("whats the date")
            name = input("whats your name")    
            file.write(name + ", "+date+", "+score+"\n")
            file.close()
            choice = input("choice")
        elif choice == "2":
            f = open("leaderboard.txt", "r")
            file_contents = f.read()
            print(file_contents)
            f.close()
            choice = input("choice")

        elif choice == "3":
            open("leaderboard.txt", 'w').close()
            print("erased")
            choice = input("choice")

print("program quit")    
file.close()
```

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question itself*. Review [ask].

Comment: Please copy your code into the question instead of a screenshot

Comment: you open/truncate for writing then try to read from the file!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at a shrunken version of your code:

```
while choice != "4":
    file = open("leaderboard.txt", "w")
    ...
    elif choice == "2":
        f = open("leaderboard.txt", "r")
```

You're first truncating the file, then trying to read from it.

You get no data, as expected.

Fix: swap the lines like this so file is open in writing only in case `1`:

```
    if choice == "1":
        file = open("leaderboard.txt", "w")
```

Comment: thank you i got it working i just needed to open the file within the if statement :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and the text file made is not blank!

It's the overwriting of the file before it is read is the reason you thought it is blank.

Here is some amended code.

```
 print ("1: Enter new high score.", "\n","2: Display scores.", "\n","3: Clear scores", "\n","4: Quit")

 choice = input("")

 while choice != "4":

    try:

        open("leaderboard.txt", "r") #Tests if the file exists

    except FileNotFoundError:

        open("leaderboard.txt", "w") #If not creates the file

    if choice == "1":

        score = input("what was your score")

        date = input("whats the date")

        name = input("whats your name")  

        file.write(name + ", "+date+", "+score+"\n")

        file.close()

        choice = input("choice")

    elif choice == "2":

        f = open("leaderboard.txt", "r")

        file_contents = f.read()

        print(file_contents)

        f.close()

        choice = input("choice")

    elif choice == "3":

        open("leaderboard.txt", 'w').close()

        print("erased")

        choice = input("choice")

print("program quit")   

file.close()
```

~Joss